# Should I detect the device or the page first?

Tags: theme-development, mobile, responsive, screen-layout

I wonder what the best practice is, if it does matter. Should I detect the device first and surround the *page block* inside of the *device block*, or the opposite?

The device detector is based on: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect, Mobble plugin.

Device block:

```
<?php if ( is_mobile() ) { ?>
  mobile
<?php } elseif ( is_tablet() ) { ?>
  tablet
<?php } else { ?>
  computer
<?php } ?>
```

Page block:

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) : ?>
  blogpage
<?php elseif( is_page() ) : ?>
  pages
<?php elseif( is_single() ) : ?>
  posts
<?php elseif ( is_category() or is_tag() ) : ?>
  category- or tag-pages
<?php endif; ?>
```

For examle:

```
<?php if ( is_mobile() ) { ?>

  <?php if ( is_home() ) : ?>
    blogpage
  <?php elseif( is_page() ) : ?>
    pages
  <?php elseif( is_single() ) : ?>
    posts
  <?php elseif ( is_category() or is_tag() ) : ?>
    category- or tag-pages
  <?php endif; ?>   

<?php } elseif ( is_tablet() ) { ?>

  tablet

<?php } else { ?>

  computer

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Why you detect the device? That's is not really solid. Everyday get it new devices. If it is a topic of the design you should create a responsive theme, different views maybe but not in depending on the device.

Comment: The reason is that I want to cut off the code for the mobile devices and optimize it. And also have an different type of content with data.

Comment: Use less code possible?

Comment: Yes, use less code. I'm from Sweden...

Comment: You want to avoid user agent sniffing _completely_ - there is no "better" way otherwise.

Comment: Why do you discourage the use of USER_AGENT? It feels very easy to use.

Comment: This article from the MDN goes into better detail why attempting to utilize the User Agent isn't a sound idea: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregarding for a moment the comments telling you to avoid user agents (because they are error prone and will probably fail on some devices - as you can see from the constant stream of bug fixes on the plugin), the answer to your narrower question is: it doesn't matter.

If A and B are independent of eachother, as in this case, there is a logical equivalence between `if A then if B do C` and `if B then if A do C` and `if (A and B) do C`.

It could be different if a lot of processing time was involved in checking the user agent and there would be a page condition where you didn't need a different version for mobile. But as you state it, you always have to check both user agent and page type before you start doing something. Then the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Then I have a follow question. WordPress offer a function that use USER_AGENT wp_is_mobile() on [function/wp_is_mobile](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/). Is there a specific problem within USER_AGENT or is it specific the USER_AGENT? Where can I read about supported devices and the topic development?

Comment: The problem is that there are new devices and hence new user_agents almost daily. Therefore, having your site depend on detecting a user_agent is not reliable. The plugin you mention, for instance, doesn't recognize increasingly popular Xiaomi smartphones, so pc content will be delivered to those.

Comment: I see, so the best thing is to reliable on css, for example: `@media only screen and (max-width: 993px){.container{width:90%}}`. Thanks for your answers!